# Method 'GetArrayLength'/'GetByteArrayRegion' could not be resolved in JNI C file

Tags: android, c, eclipse, java-native-interface, jnienv

I'm getting the following error when trying to build my Eclipse Android project in one of my JNI C files.

```
Method 'GetArrayLength' could not be resolved
Method 'GetByteArrayRegion' could not be resolved
```

I'm simply calling GetArrayLength/GetByteArrayRegion as follows:

```
jsize jsArruLen = (*env)->GetArrayLength(env,jDeviceListArr);
(*env)->GetByteArrayRegion(env,jDeviceListArr, 0, jsArruLen, (jbyte *)(pszDrive));
```

Does anyone know what's wrong? The project builds successfully on another PC.

Thanks.

Comment: try to run `ndk-build V=1` and we shall see what libraries are scanned by the linker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That means that on that other PC the libraries, that contain these two methods, are set differently. Or, maybe, on that one PC they are not set at all. Find the libraries and compare how they are installed.